# How to use abstraction in a program for comparing two array of integers and printing the common integers present in both of the arrays?

Tags: java

i am finding it really difficult to understand the use of abstraction(core java)in comparing two integer arrays and printing the common integers present in it.
.Let the integer arrays be:
 Array1-[n1,n2,n3,n4] &  Array2-[m1,m2,m3,m4]

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Because those experts have kept details abstracted from you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abstraction:
Abstraction is "To represent the essential feature without representing the back ground details."

Abstraction lets you focus on what the object does instead of how it does it.

Abstraction provides you a generalized view of your classes or object by providing relevant information.

Abstraction is the process of hiding the working style of an object, and showing the information of an object in understandable manner.

Real world Example of Abstraction: - 
Suppose you have an object Mobile Phone.

Suppose you have 3 mobile phones as following:-

Nokia 1400 (Features:- Calling, SMS)
Nokia 2700 (Features:- Calling, SMS, FM Radio, MP3, Camera)
Black Berry (Features:-Calling, SMS, FM Radio, MP3, Camera, Video Recording, Reading E-mails)

Abstract information (Necessary and Common Information) for the object "Mobile Phone" is make a call to any number and can send SMS."

so that, for mobile phone object you will have abstract class like following:-

```
abstract class MobilePhone
{
    public void Calling();
    public void SendSMS();
}

public class Nokia1400 : MobilePhone
{

}

public class Nokia2700 : MobilePhone
{
    public void FMRadio();
    public void MP3();
    public void Camera();
}

public class BlackBerry : MobilePhone
{
    public void FMRadio();
    public void MP3();
    public void Camera();
    public void Recording();
    public void ReadAndSendEmails();

}
```

Ref:http://pankajtiwarii.blogspot.in/p/oops-abstraction-encapsulation.html?m=1

Answer (score 0):

Consider that you have a Car and when people asks you what vehicle you have, if your answer is a Car or Bike it is abstract if you specify the brand it becomes more detailed.Just giving high level details by hiding the specification and implementation becomes abstraction